# Функция "Другие приложения разработчика"

Tags: swift, appstore

Есть кнопка в ios-приложении "Другие наши продукты"  на которую поставил код:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://appstore.com/NameFamily")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
webb.loadRequest(request)
```

где NameFamily это аккаунт разработчика, код выдает пустой экран в App Store 
Приложении в магазине всего одно но будет больше ...  что пошло не так?

Answer (score 1):

Откройте список Ваших приложений в iTunes и скопируйте ссылку на страницу через функцию "Поделиться".

Comment: Этот вариант скопирует в буфер код для соцсетей , а пункт "Скопировать ссылку" тоже  не работает

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена! Код предстaвленный в вопросе работает! Был глюк XCode или моего Iphone